# Url rewriting mod_rewrite file URL with number point to same filename without the number

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have several text files with numbers in the end of the filename and I want to point each one to the same file but without the number. How can I achieve this?

```
example.com/doc1.txt --> example.com/doc.txt
example.com/doc2.txt --> example.com/doc.txt
example.com/doc3.txt --> example.com/doc.txt
```

I want to keep the url with the number, just have it pointed to the doc.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that for `.txt`files, with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+)\d+\.txt$ $1.txt [NC,L]
```

In the `.htaccess` file.

If it's only for this `doc.txt` file, use:

```
RewriteRule ^doc\d+\.txt$ doc.txt [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!